# Finding elements by xpath in Appium using XCUITEST driver

Tags: xpath, appium, xctest, appium-ios

The task of updating an automation framework has fallen upon me. I'm new to iOS testing so I'm having trouble with the new XCUITEST driver in Appium-1.6.0-beta1.

I have the driver up and running, but the majority of elements are located using xpaths in the framework (not at all ideal I know) the majority of elements do not have labels, names, or accessibility tags. Thus :name locators are ruled out for 90% of elements at the moment.

The xpaths seem to be catering to the old apple framework (UIAutomation) and look like the following:

`//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[4]/UIAAlert[1]`

I have tried soemthing like this:

`//XCUIApplication[1]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[4]/XCUIElementTypeAlert[1]`

These are passed into `driver.find_element(:xpath, xpath_value)` With no luck. I can't seem to find any documentation on this, and have had minimal success on the appium discussion forum.

Can anyone point me to a working example, or documentation? Any better way to do this?

Any input would really help!

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you can't add accessibility tags to the elements in question?

Comment: I have no control over dev and due to the sheer size of the application it would be a long process. I'm stuck with xpaths for certain elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all of the XCUI elements are direct transfers from UIAutomator. The way I have been using is to run the tests without the xpaths you need and when you open onto the screen you desire go:

`System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());`

Then it is a matter of reading that XML to get the desired item. A lot more tedious but without the appium inspector in 1.6BetaX it's the only way I know how to get the XCUI hierarchy.

Comment: There are some third party software now that potentially could make this easier such as https://github.com/mykola-mokhnach/Appium-iOS-Inspector I personally haven't had the opportunity to try it but could be worth looking into as printing page source is a long process.

Answer (score 0):

With little workaround, you can use the old graphical appium to find xpath of view elements for using with Appium v1.6 Follow the step 1 in this link on medium: 
[The good old Appium inspector, with a bit workaround](https://medium.com/@chenchaoyi/the-options-of-inspecting-ios-10-app-with-appium-1-6-534ba166b958#.nlnvi9xsb)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer by JaysonP works fine but there still is a way to use the appium inspector.

1. Run appium you are using (appium 1.6.x ) from terminal/command line
2. Open appium GUI application but Do NOT run it
3. In the GUI, give the App Path
4. Make sure both the GUI version and the one you are running on terminal are using the same port. Once again DO NOT launch appium from the GUI
5. Click the Inspector button without launching appium
6. Inspector window should be opened and you can use the way you have been using it previously